# Create a view combining two tables, prioritizing rows from one

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm altering a table with a crap ton of data, which is going to take weeks to run. In the meantime, I'm creating a new table to write to while the original table is locked.

```sql
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE LIKE (OLD_TABLE INCLUDING ALL);
```

If I do this, I need to update my queries to read from both tables. So I'm creating a view combining both tables, which I'll use to query for the next month.

```sql
CREATE VIEW TABLE_VIEW AS
   SELECT * FROM NEW_TABLE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM OLD_TABLE
```

On updates, I'll have to copy rows from `OLD_TABLE` into `NEW_TABLE` with certain fields changed. For example:

Old query:

```sql
UPDATE OLD_TABLE SET isPerson=false WHERE id=123 AND name=john
```

New query:

```sql
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE (id, name, color, team, isPerson)
   SELECT id, name, color, team, false
   FROM OLD_TABLE
   WHERE id = 123
   AND name = john
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE isPerson = false
```

This means there will be duplicate data (based on my primary keys) across the tables, in which case the corresponding rows in `OLD_TABLE` would be outdated. How do I create the view to only include the rows from `NEW_TABLE` when the same primary keys exist in both tables?

(Assume primary keys are id and name, and no other constraints on the table)

Comment: I think you need to reconsider your goal and your approach. Is your table a complete stand-alone entity? It has no foreign keys of its own and there are no foreign keys from other tables to it? And apparently "locked" does not mean what it implies since you specifically state that you will "copy rows from OLD_TABLE into NEW_TABLE". Locked, to me, means OLD_TABLE will not be directly updated. Is that incorrect? A few sample rows and some simple insert/update/delete examples would help clarify.

Comment: And please tag correctly. MySQL and SQL Server are very different engines using very different dialects.

Comment: Yes, OLD_TABLE will not be directly updated. But I can read from it, so I can take rows and insert them into NEW_TABLE.

Comment: And yes it is stand-alone. No foreign keys

Comment: I added an example of a statement I'm updating

Comment: You need to add to  `FROM OLD_TABLE OT WHERE NOT EXIST( SELECT 1 FROM NEW_TABLE NT WHERE [your primary key here]` . It's impossible to write answer without knowledge what are the primary keys or other unique constraints in your tables. So you will have duplicated rows but only rows from NEW_TABLE will be shown.

Comment: @AlexYu Primary keys are id and name. There are not other constraints on the table. What is `OT` and `NT`?

Comment: @bbpi IDK who minused your question. What you describe has valid use-cases. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

## Preface

IDK why somebody minused OP question.

Consider scenario:

- during day there is a lot of copies by single row from old table to new
- combination of INSERT and DELETE is avoided because it has additional cost
- during night there a massive cleanup of copied records from old_table
- but users must see combined result without doubles

That's an absolutely valid use-case.

## Answer

What OP needs is to use `NOT EXISTS` predicate:

```sql
CREATE VIEW TABLE_VIEW AS
SELECT * FROM NEW_TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM OLD_TABLE OT
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT 1 FROM NEW_TABLE NT
     WHERE
       NT.id = OT.id
       AND NT.name = OT.name
   )
```

Look: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xcEWWkaGputdHYnYqmwQhx/2

#### **UPDATE**. More pedantic and correct answer

Note that by SQL Standard order is not guaranteed without `ORDER BY`.

On most RDBMSs UNION ALL returns rows from top to bottom.

But don't forget that by SQL Standard order of rows is not guaranteed without `ORDER BY`

It could work now but it could be broken after even a minor patch.

So to make such view absolutely correct some changes to tables are needed.

E.g. add a new field `insert_date` into tables or even:

```sql
CREATE VIEW TABLE_VIEW AS
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, 0 as display_order FROM NEW_TABLE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 1 as display_order FROM OLD_TABLE OT
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM NEW_TABLE NT
        WHERE
        NT.id = OT.id
        AND NT.name = OT.name
    )
)
ORDER BY display_order
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xcEWWkaGputdHYnYqmwQhx/3

### Notes

Just using `UNION` **could** gives the same results

But:

- IDK if it's  guaranteed. Not by SQL standard that's for sure
- it would be more performant with a lot of records (no hidden DISTINCT )